# GitLab-CI : restrict parallel pipes for the same branch

Tags: gitlab

We just migrated from Jenkins to GitLab-CI and have a pipe with multiple stages like

```
build -> test 1 -> test 2 -> test 3 -> deploy
```

Artifacts are produced during the build stage and the same are used during the subsequent stages and the total time for a pipe to run is ~2hrs.

Our setup is in such a way that if another pipe for the same branch starts parallelly then it overwrites the existing artifacts created by the previous pipe and the previous pipe fails.

Lets say we have a pipe #1 for the branch `master` running already and another pipe #2 starts for `master` after 30 mins, then the artifact of pipe #1 are removed and it fails.

In case of Jenkins we were able to restrict parallel pipes using the below configuration :

```
options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
}
```

But we are not able to find a similar configuration for GitLab-CI.

We already tried the solution suggested by '@Simon Schrottner' in the comments section but it works only at a job level but not at a pipeline level, we added the resource_group for all the jobs in the pipe as shown below :

```
build:
  script: echo "build"
  resource_group: "group1"

test:
  script: echo "test"
  resource_group: "group1"

deploy:
  script: echo "deploy"
  resource_group: "group1"
```

Note that we run all the jobs in the pipe sequentially.

But with this setup instead of waiting for the first pipe to finish all the jobs, the jobs from both the pipes were executed randomly as shown below

**Expected** : Pipe #2 wait till all the stages of Pipe #1 is finished

```
Pipe #1 : build(started) -> test -> deploy
Pipe #2 : build(waiting) -> test -> deploy

Pipe #1 : build(finished) -> test(started) -> deploy
Pipe #2 : build(waiting) -> test -> deploy

Pipe #1 : build(finished) -> test(finished) -> deploy(started)
Pipe #2 : build(waiting) -> test -> deploy

Pipe #1 : build(finished) -> test(finished) -> deploy(finished)
Pipe #2 : build(started) -> test -> deploy
```

**Actual** : Jobs are started randomly from each pipe

```
Pipe #1 : build(started) -> test -> deploy
Pipe #2 : build(waiting) -> test -> deploy

Pipe #1 : build(finished) -> test -> deploy
Pipe #2 : build(started) -> test -> deploy

Pipe #1 : build(finished) -> test -> deploy
Pipe #2 : build(finished) -> test(started) -> deploy

Pipe #1 : build(finished) -> test(started) -> deploy
Pipe #2 : build(finished) -> test(finished) -> deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define `resource_group` which do the same thing as `disableConcurrentBuilds` like

```yaml
job:
  script: echo "test"
  resource_group: "group1"
```

see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#resource_group

Comment: i see, additionally the only thing i can recommend is to change versioning to an more pipeline suitable mode for the artifacts like ` git describe --tags --always --first-parent` this way versioning is always unique for the pipeline, and you do not have issues with artifacts - or instead of this, pass the artifacts as job artifacts to the next stage.

Comment: and you can have downstream pipelines with resource group --- see  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#pipeline-level-concurrency-control-with-cross-projectparent-child-pipelines

Comment: the resource_group works at a job level but not at the pipeline level, we tried this already but it did not work, I have added more details about our project setup and the expected behavior to the description

Comment: but you can trigger a child pipeline - and use the trigger for the job which triggers it - please read https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#pipeline-level-concurrency-control-with-cross-projectparent-child-pipelines - this will cover your usecase. as you can extract your critical part into a child pipeline and control the resource allocation and concurrency via the trigger job